# Keep <div> element position unchanged, during browser resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm designing a website using ASP.NET web-forms,C#,bootstrap framework, using visual studio 2013. Its a gallery for an artist
to keep his work samples. I've used master-page to hold the website's menu and logo, and main content kept inside a wrapper  that contains other  elements in order to keep images. here is the default.aspx html code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/main/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"  
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="kiobic.main.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="../css/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script src="../css/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../css/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script> 
<script src="../css/js/jquery.js" ></script>         
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">    
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="col-lg-8-W940" id="mainContainer">    
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer1" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/1.png"/>
       <div><h6>Immortal</h6></div>
   </div>       
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer3" class="col-md-4-w278"><div><img src="media/2.jpg"/">
   </div>   </div>
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer4" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/3.jpg"/></div>
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer5" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/4.jpg"/></div>
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer6" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/5.jpg"/></div>
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer7" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/6.jpg"/></div>
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer8" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/7.jpg"/></div>
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer9" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/8.jpg"/></div>
   <div id="artThumbNailContainer10" class="col-md-4-w278"><img src="media/9.png"/></div>       
    </div>
    </div>
   </asp:Content>
```

default.master code goes here:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.Master.cs"       
    Inherits="kiobic.main.Index1" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang=" eng">
   <head runat="server">
   <title>CyrusArt</title>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   <link href="../css/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>

    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <!-- artist name image --> 
     <div class="navbar-header" > 
            <img src="../media/Artistname_banner_resize_3.png" />
    </div> 
    <!--menu bar  -->
    <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="navbar-container-horizontal">
        <div class ="custom-menu-container"> 
            <a class="custom-link"  href="#" id ="homeHref" name ="cyrusArt">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class ="custom-menu-container"> 
            <a class="custom-link" href="#" id ="homeHref2" name ="cyrusArt">Info </a>
        </div>
        <div class ="custom-menu-container"> 
            <a class="custom-link" href ="#" id ="homeHref3" name ="cyrusArt">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class ="custom-menu-container"> 
            <a  class="custom-link"  href="#" id ="homeHref4" name ="cyrusArt">Store</a>
        </div>
        <div class ="custom-menu-container"> 
            <a class="custom-link"  href="#" id ="homeHref5" name ="cyrusArt">Blog</a>
        </div>
        <div class ="custom-menu-container"> 
            <a  class="custom-link" href ="#" id ="homeHref6" name ="cyrusArt">Advice</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
       </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="../css/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>    
        <script src="../css/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script src="../css/js/jquery.js" ></script>    
      < /body>
      </html>
```

![enter image description here][1]

default.aspx page looks likes this in normal manner :
![enter image description here][2]

the 'problem' is when i re-size the browser the main div is gone and the  tags inside move around the page. i want to prevent elements from moving on browser re-size. i also used postion:fixed in my css code but it doesn't make any changes.
this is website after re-sizing browser :
 ![enter image description here][3]

as you see there wrapper  is gone.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap styles? due to `float` css property it is behaving like that

Comment: yes , i used bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Add one `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

After Navbar html section.
OR
Before `div` with `id= mainContainer`.

Comment: there is only 'clearfix' class , I've used it and the problem still persists.

Comment: what version of bootstrap you're using?

Comment: I think some other markup exist in between `mainContainer` and `navbar`, add `clearfix div` after `navbar`.

Comment: i use bootstrap , pls consider that i use master page.

Comment: a part of the problem solved! but 'mainContainer' steel disappears after re-sizing and <div> tags re position themselves.

Comment: Add your html in the question, so that we can understand what you're doing?